# If render functions should be pure, how the view can get changed based on state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stateless

I am new to react and while going through the tutorials I found this ,

- "The render() function should be pure, meaning that it does not modify component state, it returns the same result each time it's invoked, and it does not directly interact with the browser." - https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#reference

I am little confused with this. If render function should return same result each time how can I modify the display based on states ?

For example I have text with edit button. When I click on edit,  text-box should appear with content of text and edit button changes to save.

Comment: I think the render is a function of the view component of mvc. The model and controller you can modify with flux or redux. In short: Start with default state/Model => give view the state and state generates html => user clicks something so view creates an action => action is handled by store (flux/redux) and action handler returns new state => new state is given to view => ...

Comment: The render function should always return the same result for the *current* state. The render function is basically a function that takes the current state as argument (and in fact, that's what stateless components do).

Comment: http://www.slideshare.net/nikgraf/react-redux-introduction slide 33

Comment: Calling a pure function with the same set of arguments will always return the same value

Answer (score 1):

> "The render() function should be pure, meaning that it does not modify component state, it returns the same result each time it's invoked, and it does not directly interact with the browser." - https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#reference

is absolutely a correct statement in react. Changing a state cannot be done can't inside a `render` method. You can access the state inside the render but change. To change the state we use `setState` function in callback method which set the new state and ready to change anywhere in your component.

Note: `setState` expects the state to be initialized first. `getInitialState` is the function for the same and given in example below

eg.

```js
var firstName = 'Anand';
var testExample = React.createClass({
    getDefaultProps: function () {
        return {
            name: 'React',
            message: 'This is the default message!'
        };
    },
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            name: this.props.name
        };
    },
    handleNewName: function (name) {
        this.setState({
            name: name
        });
    },
    render: function () {
        var name = this.state.name;
        var message = this.props.message;

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{message}</h1>
                <h2>{name}</h2>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Inside the `handleNewName` function we have changed the state which then used inside render. Hope this helps